# solaris 10 + display 2 lines after match by grep?

Tags: shell-script, grep, solaris

I want to match for example:

The string **e1000g0** from the **lltconfig -a list**  ,  and then to display the two lines after the string e1000g0

so I get only the lines:

```
       Node   0 du1a      :   00:21:28:14:76:68
       Node   1 du1b      :   00:21:28:59:72:C4  permanent
```

please advice how the get only the two lines after?

full example from ( lltconfig -a list  ):

```
 lltconfig -a list
 Link 0 (e1000g0):
       Node   0 du1a      :   00:21:28:14:76:68
       Node   1 du1b      :   00:21:28:59:72:C4  permanent


 Link 1 (e1000g1):
       Node   0 du1a      :   00:21:28:14:76:69
       Node   1 du1b      :   00:21:28:59:72:C5  permanent


 Link21 (e1000g2):
       Node   0 du1a      :   00:21:28:14:76:49
       Node   1 du1b      :   00:21:28:59:72:A5  permanent
```

I also try this ( but its work only for linux and not on solaris -:(

```
       lltconfig -a list | grep -A 4 "e1000g0"  | grep -v "e1000g0"
       grep: illegal option -- A
       Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .
```

Comment: look for ggrep on Solaris.  Possibly in /opt/sfw/bin, /usr/sfw/bin, or /usr/gnu/bin, depending on when or how it may have been installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
var='Link 0'
lltconfig -a list |
    awk '/'"$var"'/{l=1;next} /(^$)/{l=0} l==1  {print}'
```

If you'd like something more general :

```
grep="pattern" # the string where we begin
max=4          # the number of lines after the matched pattern
awk '/'"$grep"'/{l=1;count=NR;next} l>0 && NR-count < '"$max"+1' {print}'
```

(tested on `Solaris11`)

Comment: not good because its also bring the lines for e1000g1  ( I need only the lines for e1000g0 )

Comment: how to export "Link 0" into awk , because some times its Link 1 ... etc ( I need this as parameter , not as static value )

Comment: See my edited post.

Comment: great thx allot

Comment: Added a more generic `awk` command.

Comment: You should use the -v option to awk to use the shell variable.

Answer (score 4):

Solaris 11 has GNU egrep, which can provide contextual lines using -A or -B.

Or, if you don't have GNU grep/egrep, then the `cgrep` script at http://www.intuitive.com/wicked/showscript.cgi?036-cgrep.sh provides a contextual grep with a similar function.

Answer (score 0):

`lltconfig -a list | awk 'BEGIN{n=0}/e1000g0/{n=NR}n&&NR>n&&NR<n+3{print}'`

Comment: lltconfig -a list | awk 'BEGIN{n=0}/e1000g0/{n=NR}n&&NR>n&&NR<n+3{print}'
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1